# Allocated Pick quantity from one column to other column

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I am trying to allocate Pick Quantity from total Quantity and remaining quantity should be assign to last row. What I am doing I have two Products (CEOO1, CEOO1) with Quantity 50 each and it can allocated 15 to each box. I divide Quantity to Size and generate rows using `spt_values` and Want to allocate to box based on size and in my case 3 rows will assign 15 and last rows will assign 5 for Product CEOO1. What I have tried is below.

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductCode  NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    Quantity     INT NULL,
    Size         INT NULL    
)

INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('CEOO1',50,15)
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES('CEOO2',50,15)

SELECT ProductCode, 
        Quantity, 
        Size, 
        Quantity - SUM(Size) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductCode ORDER BY ProductCode ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS Remaing,0 Allocated  FROM (
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ProductCode,Quantity,Size, CEILING(CAST(Quantity AS float)/CAST(Size AS FLOAT)) TotalRows FROM @TempTable
) AS detail
CROSS APPLY 
                    (SELECT     DISTINCT number 
                    FROM        master.dbo.spt_values 
                    WHERE       number>0 AND number<=detail.TotalRows
                    ) RowGen    

) AS ProductAllocation
```

It giving result like

[image]

but i want like this

[image]

Comment: How do you come up with `Allocated = 3` for both last row of the `ProductCode` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made few modification to your query. Mainly added the logic for calculating `Allocated`. I uses `number` in descending order such that when `number = 1`, it is the last row

```
SELECT  
    t.ProductCode,  
    t.Quantity, 
    t.Size,
    Remaining   = t.Quantity - SUM(t.Size) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ProductCode 
                                                     ORDER BY RowGen.number DESC),
    Allocated   = CASE  WHEN    RowGen.number <> 1
                        THEN    t.Size
                        ELSE    t.Quantity 
                              - SUM(t.Size) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ProductCode 
                                                      ORDER BY RowGen.number DESC) 
                              + t.Size
                        END
FROM    @TempTable AS t
        CROSS APPLY 
        (
            SELECT  DISTINCT number 
            FROM    master.dbo.spt_values 
            WHERE   number > 0 
            AND     number <= CEILING(t.Quantity * 1.0 / t.Size)
        ) AS RowGen    
ORDER BY t.ProductCode, RowGen.number DESC

/* Result 
CEOO1   50  15  35  15
CEOO1   50  15  20  15
CEOO1   50  15  5   15
CEOO1   50  15  -10 5
CEOO2   50  15  35  15
CEOO2   50  15  20  15
CEOO2   50  15  5   15
CEOO2   50  15  -10 5
*/
```